# Data Type Mismatch in code - why now?

Tags: vba, ms-access

up to now my code has been working fine - but for some unknown reason it doesn't work anymore and is throwing as error:

```
Run-time error '13':
Type mismatch
```

Here is where the error is occurring:

```
Dim rst As Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryGetEventsByNonPharmacists")
```

The query exists and it a basic SELECT query. This has never been a problem before so why is this throwing an error?

Thanks

Comment: what about the query itself? does that give any errors?

Comment: no it doesn't was the first thing i looked at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should probably be:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
```

While you can get away with Recordset as long and you do not have a reference to the ADO libraries, or when the ADO libraries come after the DAO library, for the most part your are much better off always using an explicit reference to the library for the Recordset.

Comment: I added a comment. Also, you may have been using an sql string  before.

Comment: im starting to understand why people dislike VBA

Comment: Trust me, they are all as bad as one another :)